# can we find a continuous surjection from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{\omega}$?

Tags: general-topology

I've shown there exist continuous onto map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for any finite $n$. Now my question can we find a continuous surjection from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ ? Where $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is the usual notation and it has product topology. (I can see its not possible with box topology because $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ with box topo is not connected)

Comment: Given continuous surjections $f_n\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]^n$, you can probably stitch them togther to cover $\Bbb R^\omega$, which is the union of a sequence of subsets homeomorphic to $[0,1]^n$ (for example, the $n$th subset is $[-n,n]^n \times {0}^\omega$).

Comment: @Greg Martin . That would fail to include any sequence $(x_n)_{n\in  \omega}$ $\in R^{\omega}$  for which $\{n: x_n\ne 0\}$ is infinite,

Comment: Good point, darn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74766/is-0-1-omega-a-continuous-image-of-0-1?rq=1) gives a solution to your question. Spoiler alert: the answer appears to be "no."